# Dividing string equally into an array Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a very big random string (100 characters) stored as x:

6968616133301555455570257259682193685987560804534570102824632431711170128128496642744577106517204749

how can I separate this string equally into 10 strings with 10 characters, and store it in an array?

I know they are all numbers, but I need it to work with letters as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through and split the string with something like this:

```
x = "6968616133301555455570257259682193685987560804534570102824632431711170128128496642744577106517204749"
target_size = 10
count = len(x) / target_size
split = [ x[i:i+target_size] for i in range(0, len(x), target_size) ]
print split
```

Comment: Man, than you soooo much! I was stuck on this for like 3 days, wasn't expecting anyone to figure this out.